.Net Aspire Redis Error 404 - This Container App is stopped or does not exist
I have published the .net aspire application. I can access the frontend, but when I am accessing the Redis service cache, it gives the below error.

I verified in the Azure portal, it's running fine.


Error 404 - This Container App is stopped or does not exist.

While publishing it says that it's deployed successfully.

5/25/2024 7:53:29 PM: Info   (✓) Done: Deploying service cache
5/25/2024 7:53:29 PM: Info   - Endpoint:
https://cache.internal.wittywave-b8815387.centralindia.azurecontainerapps.io/


Did you figure this out?

In Container app settings, check if Ingress Traffic is set to 'Limited to Container Apps Environment'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/ingress-overview#external-and-internal-ingress

I tried changing Ingress Traffic to Accepting traffic from anywhere. But its also not helping

Are you using the url from the app overview?

Yes, I used the same irl as well
